# How to make column cell-array from column struct array in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, struct, cell-array

Suppose I get directory list with

```
files = dir(mypattern);
```

Now I have 10000x1 struct in `files`.

If I do

```
filenames = {files.name};
```

I will have 1x10000 cell in `filenames`.

I.e. with transposed orientation.

How to get 10000x1 cell from `files` in one step here?

Comment: why is it so problematic?

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
filenames = {files.name}.';
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to explain what is happening. `files.name` is a [Comma-Separated List](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) which behaves like `{files(1).name,files(2).name,files(3).name}` (simplifying to three elements) because it is separated by comma, not by a semicolon. There is no Semicolon-Separated List or similar, you have to transpose or reshape to get the dimensions you want.

For vectors the solution from Shai is perfect, `reshape` is a simple solution which also applies to more dimensional data structures:

```
files=struct('names',{'a','b';'c','d'}); %example data 2x2
reshape({files.names},size(files));
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way is:

```
filenames = arrayfun(@(x) x.name, dir(mypattern), 'uni',0);
```